# swiftUI array.first(where: not working with struct/class array

Tags: arrays, class, struct, swiftui, where-clause

I am trying to find a string within an array using this code;

```
var userArray = [UserItem]()

var foundUser: String {
    guard let findUser = userArray.first(where: { $0 == item.name }) else { return "Not found" }
    return findUser
}
```

But I am getting the following error message;
"Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> Bool' to expected argument type '(UserList) throws -> Bool'"

So I tried adding a standard array;

```
var userArray = ["1", "Gale Dyer", "3", "4"]
```

and got rid of the error and the result I intended.

I assume it is because my struct or class does not conform to String but I am not sure how I fix this as adding ", String" doesn't seem to be the answer.

For reference here is the other data;

```
struct UserItem: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var isActive: Bool
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var company: String
    var email: String
    var address: String
    var about: String
//    var registered: Date
    var tags: [String]
    var friends: [Friend]
}

struct Friend: Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}

class UserList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [UserItem]()
        {
        didSet {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(items) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Items")
            }
        }
    }
    init() {
        if let items = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Items") {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let decoded = try? decoder.decode([UserItem].self, from: items) {
                self.items = decoded
                return
            }
        }

        self.items = []
    }
    
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check with same type in the closure of `first(where:)` method. Here's the fix.

```
var foundUser: String {
    guard let findUser = userArray.first(where: { $0.name == item.name })?.name else { return "Not found" }
    return findUser
}
```